# Wondering if my sentence written grammatically correct

Tags: grammar

I'm having my hair cut. ( I meant to say this is my decision to ask a barber to cut my hair during this week.

Comment: *during* would suggest a period stretching for the whole week. You don't require any preposition here. Check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you plan for a hair cut in this week. Say it that way only!

> *I'll have my haircut this week.* **If you are pretty sure (and confirmed),** you may also say... 
>   *I'm having my haircut this week.* Adding *this week* would remove an ambiguity and make it clear that you have this plan.

**I'm having my hair cut** - is a complete sentence and would mean that you are having your haircut now. Something like if someone is asking that what are you doing, you may simply answer *I'm having my haircut, talk to you later.*

Comment: +1; does `talk you later` convey as `talk to you later`?

Comment: @SparKotॐ Yes...though it's quite informal but okay in speech!

Comment: @SparKotॐ No, *\*talk you later* is ungrammatical.

Comment: @SparKotॐ it's ungrammatical but spoken in an informal way as I already said. You can use it in an informal speech -as in my example. Google Book shows result of it - Falling for the Princess- By *Sandra Hyatt.*

Comment: It's ungrammatical even informally.

Comment: I'm *getting* a haircut (or getting *my* hair cut) is more commonly heard. That doesn't make "*having*" wrong, it just sounds a bit odd, in the US anyway.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Whether in the US or anywhere, if you compare two sentences *I'm having my hair cut* and *I'll have my hair cut **this week*** they are different. You may re-read my answer that clarifies it.

Comment: I would say "I'm getting my hair cut on Tuesday" or "I'm getting my hair cut this week". I don't think I've ever actually heard anyone say they are having a haircut (now or at a later time).

Comment: BTW, Haircut is a noun. So, you get a haircut or your hair cut. Or *have* your hair cut, like I said, it isn't wrong.

Comment: BTW, @Jolenealaska Haircut is a noun which **also** means *the act of cutting the hair*

Comment: Yes, again, not as commonly. I looked in three dictionaries before I found one that used the term in that way (Oxford).